# Google Maps Center while zooming

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am using google maps in my ios app and I have fixed the marker in the centre of the view so as to get the centre location. Now, while zooming the marker is somewhere else and the current location is somewhere else.what I want to achieve is while zoomingIn or out my location should be in the centre of the map View how can I achieve it. Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Means you try to restrict the user only zoom in and out must be in center  right?

Comment: when zooming in or out current location should be in the centre of the map

Comment: I think you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830516/prevent-scrolling-in-a-mkmapview-also-when-zooming

Comment: Hi thanks for your effort but as i said am using google maps sdk in ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this line [`allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_u_i_settings#overview) to your GMSMapview. This setting controls whether rotate and zoom gestures can be performed off-center and scrolled around.

```
mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = NO
```

For more information, check this [page](http://www.ceus-now.com/zoom-without-changing-camera-center/) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990873/google-maps-sdk-ios-prevent-map-from-changing-location-on-zoom).

Comment: Thanks a lot you solved my problem @KENdi have a great day cheers!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your situation, you have a marker in the center of your map and then you want, in case the user make a Zoom to the map that the marker remain in the center.  Well, that is achieved  with this logic:  You have to listen to the "Zoom changed" event of google map. In case this event is triggered, retrieve the coordinates of the center and recreate the marker with the new coordinates. Doing this in plain javascript is easy, but for what I am seeing now,  in IOS could be a little bit more complicated.  But, there are some links that I hope could help you:

**To detect a Zoom Changed in GoogleMaps SDK IOS:**
[Is there a Google Map event listener for panning or zooming map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617723/is-there-a-google-map-event-listener-for-panning-or-zooming-map)

**To get the coordinates from the map center in GoogleMaps SDK IOS:**
[How to get coordinate center of gmsmapview in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103390/how-to-get-coordinate-center-of-gmsmapview-in-iphone)